# @OneToMany in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, hibernate

I have 2 entities with the one-many relationship that's one address can be of many employees.

MySQL Database:

**Address**

- address_id INT PK AutoIncr
- city VARCHAR
- country VARCHAR

**Employee**

- id PK AutoIncr
- first_name VARCHAR
- last_name VARCHAR
- email VARCHAR
- registration_date date
- employee_id INT FK

I have following entities in hibernate, I want to get list of all employees having particular location.

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<mapping class="com.example.bean.EmployeeBean"/>
<mapping class="com.example.bean.AddressBean"/>

@Entity
@Table(name="ADDRESS")
public class AddressBean {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="ADDRESS_ID")
    private int addressId;

    @Column(name="CITY")
    private String city;

    @Column(name="COUNTRY")
    private String country;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="EMPLOYEE")
    private ArrayList<EmployeeBean> employeeList;

    public int getAddressId() {
        return addressId;
    }
    public void setAddressId(int addressId) {
        this.addressId = addressId;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
    public ArrayList<EmployeeBean> getEmployeeList() {
        return employeeList;
    }
    public void setEmployeeList(ArrayList<EmployeeBean> employeeList) {
        this.employeeList = employeeList;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
public class EmployeeBean {
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name="LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name="EMAIL")
    private String email;
    @Column(name="REGISTRATION_DATE")
    private String registrationDate;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getRegistrationDate() {
        return registrationDate;
    }
    public void setRegistrationDate(String registrationDate) {
        this.registrationDate = registrationDate;
    }
}
```

I get the following error while compiling.. where am I doing wrong?

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: com.example.bean.AddressBean.employeeList
```

Comment: mysql <> sqlserver. please tag appropriate technologies

Comment: Your employee bean is not annotated as entity?

Comment: I miscopied that.. it's annotated. edited

Comment: @ImamBux Do you have employee_ID column in Address?

Comment: I don't see any references between these two table on DB level.

Comment: No @Sarz I don't have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a specific implementation of a `Collection` in a `@OneToMany` relation.

You problematic part is

```
private ArrayList<EmployeeBean> employeeList;
```

You have to use

```
private List<EmployeeBean> employeeList;
```

Also note that a `List` also needs some kind of ordering criteria, therefore it is possible better to use a `Set`:

```
private Set<EmployeeBean> employeeList;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the collection interfaces. In your case it should be

> List

instead of

> ArrayList

Or better yet *Set*.

So this should do the trick:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="EMPLOYEE")
private List<EmployeeBean> employeeList;
```

You should change other parts of the beans as well.

Answer (score 0):

1°) use interface instead of implementation:

```
private List<EmployeeBean> employeeList;
```

2°) in EmployeeBean where is the column for AddressBean?
in AddressBean:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="address")
private List<EmployeeBean> employeeList;
```

in EmployeeBean:

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "ADDRESS")
private AddressBean address;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have two problems:

First one: design of your table structure. As you mentioned multiple employees can have single address. So employee table should have a column which carries address_id. So in your Employee beam you have to create a reference for that.

Second one: You have to List or Set instead of Arraylist `private ArrayList<EmployeeBean> employeeList;`or `private Set<EmployeeBean> employeeList;`

Hope so this might help you.

Use `private List<EmployeeBean> employeeList;` or

Answer (score 0):

I suggested following change

DB= add foreign key address_id in employee table. As every employee should have an Address and one Address can be mapped with multiple employees

**Address**

- address_id INT PK AutoIncr
- city VARCHAR
- country VARCHAR

**Employee**

- id PK AutoIncr
- first_name VARCHAR
- last_name VARCHAR
- email VARCHAR
- registration_date date
- address_id INT FK,
- employee_id INT FK

If you are using Eclipse IDE use JPA TOOL for generating Entities.

Address Entity

```
@Entity
    @Table(name="ADDRESS")
    public class AddressBean {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name="ADDRESS_ID")
        private Integer addressId;

        @Column(name="CITY")
        private String city;

        @Column(name="COUNTRY")
        private String country;

         //GETTER SETTER
    }
```

Employee Entity

```
@Entity
    @Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
    public class EmployeeBean {
        @GeneratedValue
        @Id
        @Column(name="ID")
        private Integer id;

        @Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
        private String firstName;

        @Column(name="LAST_NAME")
        private String lastName;

        @Column(name="EMAIL")
        private String email;

        @Column(name="REGISTRATION_DATE")
        private String registrationDate;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy="ADDRESS_ID")
        private List<Address> address;

        @Column(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")
        private List<EmployeeBean> employeeList;     //GETTER SETTER
    }
```

Now your SQL query would be like:

```
SQL: 'Select * from Employee where Address_Id = 10'
```

Answer (score 0):

An SQL JOIN clause is used to combine rows from two or more tables, based on a common field between them. 
You must have a common column between both the entities to let Hibernate join the tables for you.

So create a reference of `AddressBean` in `EmployeeBean`

`@Entity
 @Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
 public class EmployeeBean{`

`....`

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="ADDRESS_ID")
private AddressBean address_ID;
```

`//getter setter`

`}`

And then you can fetch the Address of an Employee with watever method you follow, simplest being `session.get(AddressBean.class,addressId);`
Hibernate internally will perform the join for you and return AddressBean object for a particualr Employee.

Further, you can follow [this link](http://levelup.lishman.com/hibernate/hql/joins.php) to learn and perform joins using Hibernate Query Language to get list of all employees having particular location.

And there is no need to set the return type to specific implementation of collection, in this case, `ArrayList`. However, even if you do, there isnt any issue. You will have to cast it to `(ArrayList)query.list();` or similar type cast wherever compiler throws error. Although JBoss community documentation for Hibernate suggests to use `Set` as return type when dealing with joins. Choice is yours.

Lastly, i'd suggest you to add `@Cascade` in AddressBean Class. Adding cascade = “all” ensures that any changes in parent class object will effect in child class object too, and all operations like insert, delete, update on parent object will enforce the changes in child object too. (Referential Integrity)

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="EMPLOYEE")
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL) //ANNOTATION TO ADD
private ArrayList<EmployeeBean> employeeList;
```